# Is there a way to half-close a FILE* file-handle?

Tags: macos, child-process, shutdown, stdio

My situation is this:  In MacOS/X, I've called [AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1540038-authorizationexecutewithprivileg) to spawn a privileged child process, and the only way I have to communicate with the child process is by calling `fread()` and/or `fwrite()` on the `FILE *` file-handle returned to me by the final argument to that call.

What I want to do is indicate to the child process that it should go away, which I can do by calling `fclose()` on the file-handle -- the child process sees that its `STDIN_FILENO` has closed and responds by exiting.

However, I also want to be able to read any text that the child process printed to its `stdout` stream before exiting, but calling `fclose()` on the file-handle precludes doing that.

So my question is, is there any way to "half-close" a `FILE *`, such that is becomes closed-for-writing but still-open-for-reading?  I'm imagining something analogous to the [shutdown(SHUT_WR)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/shutdown) that can be used on a socket-descriptor.

Comment: I don't think so. You may need to use a protocol with "commands" with the child process and send an explicit "close" command to it.